# finding dx dy dz from cube Coordinates using python

Tags: python

I have an uneven 3D cube defined by the following coordinates :

```
'''
[ 1.12301886  1.19284666 -0.00300979]
[ 1.1230377   1.19289529 -0.00314375]
[ 1.12316322  1.19403648 -0.00302677]
[ 1.1231823   1.19409418 -0.00315679]
[ 1.12599063  1.19226062 -0.00262304]
[ 1.1260097   1.19230449 -0.00275872]
[ 1.12613511  1.19344997 -0.00264101]
[ 1.12615454  1.1935029  -0.00277321]
'''
```

Is it possible to calculate Max and Min  >> Dx DY DZ for this cube?
The coordeintes is found already in a list of lists using numpy

```
'''
COORD = 
[[ 1.12613511  1.19344997 -0.00264101]
 [ 1.12599063  1.19226062 -0.00262304]
 [ 1.12301886  1.19284666 -0.00300979]
 [ 1.12316322  1.19403648 -0.00302677]
 [ 1.12615454  1.1935029  -0.00277321]
 [ 1.1260097   1.19230449 -0.00275872]
 [ 1.1230377   1.19289529 -0.00314375]
 [ 1.1231823   1.19409418 -0.00315679]]
'''
```

Comment: If it's already a Numpy matrix, then aren't the extents just the min and max of each axis? If you have a N-matrix of 3 coordinates, you can transpose it to get a 3-matrix of N coordinates, and then getting the min and max should be easy.

Comment: Because a cube is convex, you can do this by taking the min/max of each of the COORD[:][i].

Comment: @akx yes it is a numpy matrix,
How can i transpose it to 3-matrix .. apologies for the stuped question

Comment: thanks for ur reply, 
not very sure what do u mean by (min/max) of each coord! 
is it possible to share example?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `mat.T` returns the transposed version of `mat`.